# How to remove brackets from output?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, textarea, brackets

I'm trying to display the output of the following code example without the brackets (as you can see in my current output below)
I want to display the data in the textarea field as simple text with line break.

Does anyone know how to do this? I can't seem to find a solution without working on my corresponding HTML file. 
Thanks in advance!

```
@app.route('/show_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_user():
    form = myform()
    result = session.query(User.username).all()
    form.textarea.data = result
    return render_template('index.html', title='users.', user=current_user, form=form)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT: [('bla',), ('bli',)]
WANTED OUTPUT: 
bla
bli

I use flask and sqlalchemy.

Comment: Can't you modify your result variable? A simple list comprehension should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `result` is a list of tuples of length 1. This should work:

```
result = [('bla',), ('bli',)]
result_as_text = '\n'.join([x[0] for x in result])
print(result_as_text)
```

Output:

```
bla
bli
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed!